# Is $\nu(E) = \max\{\mu(E),\eta(E)\}$ a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\eta$ be measures on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{M})$. For $E \in \mathcal{M}$, define $\nu(E) = \max\{\mu(E),\eta(E)\}$. Is $\nu$ a measure on $(X, \mathcal{M})$?

**My Try:**
I use the fact: $$\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$
then I tried to prove that $\nu$ is a measure and though I can prove or get to a contradiction.

$$\nu(E)=\max\{ \mu(E), \eta(E) \} = \frac{\mu(E) + \eta(E) +|\mu(E)- \eta(E)|}{2}$$

1. $\nu(\emptyset)=\frac{\mu(\emptyset)+\eta(\emptyset)+|\mu(\emptyset) -\eta(\emptyset)|}{2}=0$ since $\mu$ and $\eta$ are measure.
2. Consider now a countable disjoint collection $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of measurable sets

\begin{align*}
\nu(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k) &= \frac{1}{2} \Big[\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k) +\eta(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k)+\Big|\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k)-\eta(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k)\Big|\Big]\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \Big[\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k)+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \eta(E_k)+\Big|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \eta(E_k)\Big| \Big ]\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \Big[ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big(\mu(E_k) +\eta(E_k)\Big) + \Big|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k) - \eta(E_k)\Big|\Big]
\end{align*}

Am I on the right track, because I am stuck? Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disjoint$E_k$ is the right track, but a simple counterexample suffices:
Let $X=\{a,b\}$, $\mathcal M=\mathcal P(X)$, $\mu(E)=\begin{cases}1&a\in E\\0&a\notin E\end{cases}$, $\eta(E)=\begin{cases}1&b\in E\\0&b\notin E\end{cases}$.
Then $$\nu(X)=1\ne 2=\nu(\{a\}+\nu(\{b\}).$$